# Autofill Username and Password UIWebView Swift

Tags: ios, authentication, swift, uiwebview, autofill

I've found many ways to autofill a username and password in objective-c, but I can't figure out how to make it work with Swift. What would be the Swift equivalent of this code and would this work for what I am trying to accomplish? Thanks

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
// Auto fill the username and password text fields, assuming the HTML has
// <input type="text" name="username"> and
// <input type="text" name="password">
NSString *savedUsername = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"USERNAME"];
NSString *savedPassword = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"PASSWORD"];
if (savedUsername.length != 0 && savedPassword.length != 0) {
    // Create js strings
    NSString *loadUsernameJS = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var inputFields = document.querySelectorAll(\"input[name='username']\"); \
                                for (var i = inputFields.length >>> 0; i--;) { inputFields[i].value = '%@';}", savedUsername];
    NSString *loadPasswordJS = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var inputFields = document.querySelectorAll(\"input[name='password']\"); \
                                for (var i = inputFields.length >>> 0; i--;) { inputFields[i].value = '%@';}", savedPassword];
    // Runs the JS
    [self.webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: loadUsernameJS];
    [self.webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: loadPasswordJS];
}
```

I have this but it doesn't autofill for some reason even though I have tested and the values are stored correctly and are being grabbed correctly:

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ : UIWebView){


    let savedUsername = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("USERNAME")
    let savedPassword = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("PASSWORD")

    if savedUsername == nil || savedPassword == nil {return}

    if ( countElements(savedUsername!) != 0 && countElements(savedPassword!) != 0) {
        let loadUsernameJS = "var inputFields = document.querySelectorAll(\"input[name='username']\"); \\ for (var i = inputFields.length >>> 0; i--;) { inputFields[i].value = \'\(savedUsername)\';}"
        let loadPasswordJS = "var inputFields = document.querySelectorAll(\"input[type='password']\"); \\ for (var i = inputFields.length >>> 0; i--;) { inputFields[i].value = \'\(savedPassword)\';}"
        self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(loadUsernameJS)
        self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(loadPasswordJS)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add what you have so far for your Swift implementation?

Comment: Added above based on the help I got below but it still doesn't work right and I can't figure out why

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a simple swift conversion of your provided code. SStringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString has been tested using different javascript and works correctly.

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView!) {

    let savedUsername = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("USERNAME")
    let savedPassword = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("PASSWORD")

    if savedUsername == nil || savedPassword == nil {return}

    if ( countElements(savedUsername!) != 0 && countElements(savedPassword!) != 0) {
        let loadUsernameJS = "var inputFields = document.querySelectorAll(\"input[name='username']\"); \\ for (var i = inputFields.length >>> 0; i--;) { inputFields[i].value = \'\(savedUsername)\';}"
        let loadPasswordJS = "var inputFields = document.querySelectorAll(\"input[name='password']\"); \\ for (var i = inputFields.length >>> 0; i--;) { inputFields[i].value = \'\(savedPassword)\';}"

        self.webview.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(loadUsernameJS)
        self.webview.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(loadPasswordJS)
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that the proper values are stored to NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults under USERNAME and PASSWORD but for some reason this code doesn't seem to autofill them in the webpage.

Comment: When you run a simple javascript string eval do you get a successfully response.
    `let result = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.title")
    println("\(result!)")`

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem with the code above not autofilling the web view.

Comment: I m getting javascript syntax error of backslash in the above code.
Optional(Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=4 "A JavaScript exception occurred" UserInfo={WKJavaScriptExceptionLineNumber=1, WKJavaScriptExceptionMessage=SyntaxError: Invalid escape in identifier: '\', WKJavaScriptExceptionColumnNumber=0, WKJavaScriptExceptionSourceURL=https://snapicaa.com/, NSLocalizedDescription=A JavaScript exception occurred})