# Saving username/password in UIWebView for future auto login

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, nsurlcredential

I am working to make a simple iOS app for a school website. The app has built-in UIWebView to load the login page of the website. The first time a user loads the page, he/she needs to login as before. I hope the app can then save the username/password for the user. So the next the user user the app, it autofills and submits the form to login automatically.

I have found several links from stack overflow.com are extremely helpful. For example,

[1] [Is it possible for a UIWebView to save and autofill previously entered form values (e.g., username & password)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772341/is-it-possible-for-a-uiwebview-to-save-and-autofill-previously-entered-form-valu)

[2] [Autofill Username and Password in UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140030/autofill-username-and-password-in-uiwebview)

I tried to do the same for my program. The autofill part works fine for a hardcoded test username/password. However, I have got a problem to save the credentials from the UIWebView. The "stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @" method doesn't retrieve the element from HTML.

My code is like below. I load the website with viewDidLoad and want to save the credentials with webView.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
  NSString *urlString = @"https://learn.packagingschool.com/users/sign_in";
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
  NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
  [self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
  [self.webView setDelegate:self];
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType; {

    //save form data
    if(navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeFormSubmitted) {

    //grab the data from the page
    NSString *inputEmail = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.getElementByID('user_email').value"];
    NSString *inputPassword = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.getElenebtByName('user[password]')[0].value"];

    NSLog(@"email is %@\npassword is %@", inputEmail, inputPassword);

    //store values locally
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:inputEmail forKey:@"email"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:inputPassword forKey:@"password"];

    NSLog(@"email is %@\npassword is %@", inputEmail, inputPassword);

    //[SFHFKeychainUtils storeUsername:username andPassword:password forServiceName:@"MyService" updateExisting:YES error:nil];

  }    
  return YES;
}
```

When I click the submit button in the webView, there is no string retrieved from the website.

```
2017-02-23 11:19:46.732 Packaging School[441:5425] email is 
password is 
2017-02-23 11:19:46.755 Packaging School[441:5425] email is 
password is
```

Please help me to solve the problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: try to print document.body.innerHTML, when u click the button. See if the values are in the form after u click the button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
NSString *inputEmail = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.getElementByID('user_email').value"];
NSString *inputPassword = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.getElenebtByName('user[password]')[0].value"];
```

To

```
NSString *inputEmail = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.getElementById('user_email').value"];
NSString *inputPassword = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.getElementsByName('user[password]')[0].value"];
```

Comment: Why the change? could you please provide an explanation? Thank you

Comment: @Peter Cheng Good catch! Thank you so much for finding the typo. It works now.

Comment: @Robert I have typos in the statement. "getElementByID" needs to be "getElementById". "getElenebtByName" needs to be "getElementsByName"

Answer (score -3):

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
import WKCookieWebView
import CoreLocation
import SwiftKeychainWrapper

class MoviesViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var currentLocaton: CLLocation!

lazy var webView: WKCookieWebView = {
    let webView: WKCookieWebView = WKCookieWebView(frame: self.view.bounds)
    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    webView.wkNavigationDelegate = self
    return webView

}()

@IBOutlet weak var Activity: UIActivityIndicatorView!
@IBOutlet weak var SAMBACK: UIBarButtonItem!

@IBAction func SAMBACK(_ sender: Any) {
    if webView.canGoBack{
        webView.goBack()
    }
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    Activity.stopAnimating()
    SAMBACK.isEnabled = webView.canGoBack
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
    Activity.stopAnimating()
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ArgAppUpdater.getSingleton().showUpdateWithForce()

    // SAM - Load Background webView to Black Color
    webView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 51/255, green: 51/255, blue: 51/255, alpha: 1)
    webView.isOpaque = false

    webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true

    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    if CheckInternet.Connection(){

        setupWebView()
        webView.onDecidePolicyForNavigationAction = { (webView, navigationAction, decisionHandler) in
            decisionHandler(.allow)
        }

        webView.onDecidePolicyForNavigationResponse = { (webView, navigationResponse, decisionHandler) in
            decisionHandler(.allow)
        }

        webView.onUpdateCookieStorage = { [weak self] (webView) in
            self?.printCookie()
        }

        // add activity
        self.webView.addSubview(self.Activity)
        self.Activity.startAnimating()
        self.webView.navigationDelegate = self
        self.Activity.hidesWhenStopped = true
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://www.gmail.com")!))

    }
    else{
        self.Alert(Message: "Your Device is not connect to internet, Please check your connection")
    }

    func locationAuthStatus(){
        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse{

            currentLocaton = locationManager.location
            print(currentLocaton.coordinate.latitude)
            print(currentLocaton.coordinate.longitude)
        } else {

            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            locationAuthStatus()
        }
    }
}

func Alert (Message: String){
    let alert = UIAlertController (title: "Prime Cineplex", message: "Your Device is not connect to internet, Please check your connection", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let settingsAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: .default) { (_) -> Void in
        guard let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) else {
            return
        }

        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsUrl) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl, completionHandler: { (success) in
                print("Settings opened: \(success)") // Prints true
            })
        }
    }
    alert.addAction(settingsAction)
    //let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Exit", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    //alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// MARK: - Private
private func setupWebView() {
    view.addSubview(webView)

    let views: [String: Any] = ["webView": webView]

    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
        withVisualFormat: "H:|-0-[webView]-0-|",
        options: [],
        metrics: nil,
        views: views))
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
        withVisualFormat: "V:|-0-[webView]-0-|",
        options: [],
        metrics: nil,
        views: views))
}

private func printCookie() {
    print("=====================Cookies=====================")
    HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies?.forEach {
        print($0)
    }
    print("=================================================")
}

}
```

Comment: Please note that "code only answers" are really discouraged. Just dumping 50 or 100 lines of code on somebody isnt very helpful for future readers. Focus on explaining what you are doing, too!