# Autofill Username and Password WKWebview Swift 3 Xcode

Tags: xcode, swift3, wkwebview, autofill

I am trying to make an app in Swift 3 using the WKWebView class to go to a website and autofill in the Username and password.  I have tried search for days and only find answers using Obj-C and old versions of swift.

I tried using the solution proposed here [Autofill Username and Password UIWebView Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26329771/autofill-username-and-password-uiwebview-swift)

However this did not work for me in Swift 3.  Here is my example code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import WebKit

class spot: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var container: UIView!
var webView: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    webView = WKWebView()
    container.addSubview(webView)

}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:container.bounds.width, height:container.bounds.height)
    webView.frame = frame

    // Insert URL below to change launched page
    let urlStr = "https://login.salesforce.com/"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlStr)!
    let request = NSURLRequest(url: url as URL)
    webView.load(request as URLRequest)

}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView!) {

    let savedUsername = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "USERNAME")
    let savedPassword = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "PASSWORD")

    if savedUsername == nil || savedPassword == nil {return}

    if ( countElements(savedUsername!) != 0 && countElements(savedPassword!) != 0) {
        let loadUsernameJS = "var inputFields = document.querySelectorAll(\"input[name='username']\"); \\ for (var i = inputFields.length >>> 0; i--;) { inputFields[i].value = \'\(savedUsername)\';}"
        let loadPasswordJS = "var inputFields = document.querySelectorAll(\"input[name='password']\"); \\ for (var i = inputFields.length >>> 0; i--;) { inputFields[i].value = \'\(savedPassword)\';}"

        self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(loadUsernameJS)
        self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(loadPasswordJS)
    }
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing is very important here, the id (getElementById), double check that you are using correct id, which is used in your web form.

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {

    if (email == "" || password == "") {return}

    // fill data

    let fillForm = String(format: "document.getElementById('email').value = '\(email)';document.getElementById('pass').value = '\(password)';")
    webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: fillForm)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I know its a bit late but here is my code for how I have made it work.  That said the server was expecting the string as I constructed it, but I am hoping you have the info on how your particular server is expecting the URLRequest to be constructed.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var loadingWebPage: UIActivityIndicatorView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let savedUsername = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "USERNAME")
    let savedPassword = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "PASSWORD")
    let urlStr = "https://login.salesforce.com/"

    myWebView = WKWebView()
    myWebView.uiDelegate = self
    myWebView.navigationDelegate = self

    setUrlString = "\(urlStr)?username=\(savedUsername)&password=\(savedPassword)"
    }

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    view.addSubview(myWebView)
    myWebView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let width = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myWebView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    let height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myWebView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -70)
    let top = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myWebView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 70)
    view.addConstraints([width,height,top])
    self.myWebView.addSubview(loadingWebPage)

    let myURL = URL(string: setUrlString)
    let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
    myWebView.load(myRequest)

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also, you should use KeyChain instead of UserDefaults to store the password securely.